# iOS: publish a epub or iBook in App Store

Tags: ios, epub, ibooks, newsstand-kit

I should publish an app with a interactive design.
I saw iBooks Author that is fantastic for my job.

But I saw that I can't publish an iBook as an app so I can publish it only in iBook store.
And for newsstand? Is it necessary an app?

I think also to epub with indesign, are they compatible to create an app? or they should pass as a iBook?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Files created by iBooks Author are only readable in iBooks (although iBooks now exists for iPhone/iPad/Mac so it's less restrictive than it used to be). EPUBs are also only readable in iBooks. Neither will be usable in the App Store, unfortunately.